# ReferesToRange gives Run-time Error '91':

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I keep getting "variable or with block variable not set" for the line in the for loop of the following code. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks

```
 Public Sub TestFind()

 Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))


  wsNew.Range(wsNew.Cells(1, 1), wsNew.Cells(1, 17)).Value _
             = Array("ReturnId", "GridName", "Item", "TabName", "AltFldName", "FieldPos", "Reference", "Type", _
             "SortPos", "FieldSize", "CalcField", "CellDesc", "DoNotExport", "SortStrategy", "Threshold", "IsInnerGridCell", "ReportLine")

 Dim Nm As Name
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim wb As Workbook

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
     rng = Nm.RefersToRange.Value
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you know what a **Name** is and that is what you should be looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems in the code:

1- Not all names refer necessarily to a named range. They may refer to constants, for example. So you need to add some checking before assuming that the name refers really to a range.

2- to assign a range object to a named range, you need to use `Set`

Try this:

```
Dim Nm As Name, rng As Range
For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print Nm.Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Nm.RefersToRange ' <-- Use Set to assign object references
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo NextNm ' <-- This name does not refer to a named range
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print rng.Address
   ' ... Do whatever you want with the named range
NextNm:
    On Error GoTo 0
Next Nm
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjustments made and commented.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewtr()
    Dim Nm As Name
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim var As Variant   '<~~ for numbers, dates and/or text
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Debug.Print Nm.Name
        'nm could a 'special internal name' that starts with an underscore
        'skip over these
        If Left(Nm.Name, 1) <> "_" Then
            'show the address of the defined name range - could be more than one cell
            Debug.Print Nm.RefersToRange.Address
            'do not try to assign value to a range object unless that range already has been asinged a cell or cells
            'rng = Nm.RefersToRange.Value
            'Debug.Print rng
            'this fails if Nm is more than a single cell
            'var = Nm.RefersToRange.Value
            'Debug.Print var
            'this guarantees one cell
            var = Nm.RefersToRange.Cells(1, 1).Value
            Debug.Print var
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below and report back. You have not included some of your coded i am assuming...

```
Dim Nm As Name
Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    rng = Nm.RefersToRange.Value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks but its still giving the same error for some reason. I've updated the question with more detail.